# droidninja file picker in higher version phone it gives me null error any idea how to solve it

Tags: string, post, static

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: able.works, PID: 22667
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:591)
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:565)
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:403)
    at droidninja.filepicker.utils.ImageCaptureManager.dispatchTakePictureIntent(ImageCaptureManager.java:71)
    at droidninja.filepicker.fragments.MediaFolderPickerFragment.onCameraClicked(MediaFolderPickerFragment.java:223)
    at droidninja.filepicker.adapters.FolderGridAdapter$2.onClick(FolderGridAdapter.java:97)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5623)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22433)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6316)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

Comment: This is my manifes

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. Just an error message without any code is usually not enough to help

Comment: actually i found out solution it was api and directrory error thanks for the commend tho :)